# Where to find Mavenized org.jsonpath.JsonJar?

Tags: pentaho, kettle

I'm trying to Mavenize some OSS code (PDI Kettle) which depends on org.jsonpath.JsonJar.

I suspect this might be an older or newer version related to com.jayway.jsonpath.

Is there a Maven repository out there that holds org.jsonpath.JsonJar?

Answer (score 0):

Found it ...

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>jsonpath</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsonpath</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```